# Asp .Net Core - X-Paged-List ellipsis problem

Tags: asp.net-core, pagedlist

I would like to ask if someone knows how to solve the problem where the ellipses have the same style as the other elements.
[image]

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new
{
   page      
}), new X.PagedList.Mvc.Core.Common.PagedListRenderOptions
{
   ContainerDivClasses = new[] { "navigation" },
   LiElementClasses = new[] { "page-item" },
   PageClasses = new[] { "page-link" },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

### Update

According to the comment, you want to remove the ellipsis box,right? If so, you can do this by adding `DisplayEllipsesWhenNotShowingAllPageNumbers = false` under the `PagedListRenderOptions` class.

Here is the demo for your reference:

Controller:

```
  [HttpGet("Test/{pageNo?}")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Test(int? pageNo = 1)
        {
            var data = await _context.Employee.ToListAsync();
            ViewBag.onePageOfMovies = data.ToPagedList((int)pageNo, 2);
            return View(data);
        }
```

View:

```
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core;
@using X.PagedList; 
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication_core_mvc.Controllers.Models.Employee>;
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Test</h1>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<WebApplication_core_mvc.Controllers.Models.Employee>)ViewBag.onePageOfMovies)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
@Html.PagedListPager(
    (IPagedList)ViewBag.onePageOfMovies,
    pageNo => Url.Action("Test", new { pageNo }),
    new X.PagedList.Mvc.Core.Common.PagedListRenderOptions
    {
        ContainerDivClasses = new[] { "navigation" },
        LiElementClasses = new[] { "page-item" },
        PageClasses = new[] { "page-link" },
        DisplayEllipsesWhenNotShowingAllPageNumbers = false,
    })
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time. But to be honest i do not see the difference.

Comment: I found information if you add additional attribute under "PageClasses" ->    "EllipsesFormat" = "", you are able to delete ellipsis.

Comment: @stacktracerr, In fact, you should update your question,because your question looks like you want to make the ellipsis box display normally like other boxes.However, you want to delete the ellipsis box,right? If so, then you can add `DisplayEllipsesWhenNotShowingAllPageNumbers = false` under `PagedListRenderOptions `.I have updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry for missunderstanding i dont want to delete it i want to display it as other elements.